# Cannot connect to SQL Server after upgrading from Server 2003 to Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, firewall

I upgraded my Windows Server 2003 x64 to Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, and I noticed that I cannot connect to SQL Server (from within the LAN) which is running on the computer.

I ran the OpenSqlServerPort.bat script specified on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872/en-us, however the software Firewall is still somehow blocking access from within my LAN. I installed Microsoft's Port Query tool, and it verifies that the port is being FILTERED:

```
TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED
portqry.exe -n 192.168.1.15 -e 1433 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000002.
```

I can also see in the EventLog it's being blocked:

```
The Windows Filtering Platform has blocked a packet.

Filter Information:
    Filter Run-Time ID: 74459
    Layer Name:     Transport
    Layer Run-Time ID:  12
```

I wish there were a way to lookup the filter rule which is causing the block. I did not find anything using the run-time ID on Google.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the firewall admin tools. If the firewall is active you will not ind a rule - normal mode is to block EVERYTHING that has NOT A RULE TO LET IT PASS. So, sorry, not rule to find.

You will have to put in your own rule to allow access to port 1433, TCP. Windows Advanced Firewall tool in Admin Tools.